# How to publish React JS PWA in Amazon app store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I am creating a React JS PWA web app, so that the users can install it on their mobile devices. Now the client ask to find out a way to push these PWA apps to amazon app store. So my query is whether we have tools for converting the Progressive Web Apps as APK or HTML5 Web app files so that we can put them to amazon app store.

I googled a bit and I am confused, but I am not sure which one is the right one to use and whether we can publish a PWA app to the amazon app store

Any help on this will be very grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PWA needs a browser to be executed. So if you want yo package your pwa as apk(android) you will need to implement a kind of mini-browser with pure android.

Fortunately, this task is very common and there are even online services to do that:

- https://appmaker.xyz/pwa-to-apk/
- https://pwatoapp.com/

Or if you know java:

- https://github.com/xtools-at/Android-PWA-Wrapper

Or c++

- https://github.com/RikudouSage/PwaToTwa

Or nodejs

- https://github.com/pwa-builder/CloudAPK

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Now i am fresher and tried using capacitor,finally app launches with blank page,my ref link :1==>https://capacitorjs.com/ 2=>https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/workflow  and tried using yarn instead npm yarn run build,yarn cap add andriod ,yarn cap open andriod

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Amazon Web App Tester to verify how your Web app behaves when Published to the Amazon App Store: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/webapp-app-tester.html

If it performs correctly in the tester, you can then publish the URL directly or upload your files. The full process is described here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission/publish-app-webapp-files.html

Comment: @Rijo Rajan Are you using capacitor  to run natively

Comment: Yes,now using capacitor @Anee